# Analytic Tag Distribution Issue in Customized Module

Tags: module, tags, odoo, distribution

I have created a module to retrieve the analytic tag from sale order to delivery order ie . stock.move module,

And then retrieve this value to the journal entry created after clicking the (validate) button.

If the analytic tag has analytic account distribution then it gives this error :

The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead. `Model: Analytic Line (account.analytic.line)`, `Constraint: account_analytic_line_group_id_fkey`

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks

This is the code that I have created :

```
class stockmove(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.move"

analytic_tag_ids = fields.Many2many('account.analytic.tag',store = True)



@api.model
def create(self,values):
    res = super(stockmove,self).create(values)
    if res:
        if res.sale_line_id:
            if len(res.sale_line_id.analytic_tag_ids.ids) > 0:
                res.analytic_tag_ids = [(6,0,res.sale_line_id.analytic_tag_ids.ids)]
    return res



def _prepare_account_move_line(
        self, qty, cost, credit_account_id, debit_account_id,description):
    result = super()._prepare_account_move_line(
        qty=qty, cost=cost, credit_account_id=credit_account_id,
        debit_account_id=debit_account_id, description=description)
    for res in result:
        res[2]['analytic_tag_ids'] = [(6, 0, self.analytic_tag_ids.ids)]
    return result
```